# Get video height from load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

How can I get the value of video height which is placed inside function?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7jH/)

Tried:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var videoHeight = $('video').height();
   return videoHeight; // return the value 
});

$(window).load(function(){
   videoHeight = $('video').height(); // make the globar var 
});
```

Comment: declare the variable within the scope you need to access it. If that isn't clear then you need to read about scope

Comment: updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7jH/6/)

Comment: @Rohith I need to get videoHeight value inside that function - and  then use it outside

Comment: @Rahil: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7jH/7/).

Comment: @Rohith where you were before, many thanks!